# Is there way to sticky the position of this 1st and second rows (Month and Sales Rows)

Tags: html, css

I have module where I need to set the two rows of the table sticky when the horizontal bar scroll to the right, right now I have sample codes that I created last time which is the only rows scroll to the right is the 1st row. so right now I need to find the solution to make the Month and Sales Rows sticky when it scroll to the right. to understand well, I already insert my sample code, I hope someone can help to this part. thank you.

[image: two rows to be sticky]

```css
table.agent_commission_model_historical thead th {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-size: 11.5px;
  height: 5%;
  padding: 9px !important;
  border-spacing: 40px;
}

table.agent_commission_model_historical thead th:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

table.agent_commission_model_historical tbody th {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background: #FFF;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped agent_commission_model_historical" id="tblcurrent_historical">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th colspan="2">Financial Metrics</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>

      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th colspan="2">OPS KPIs</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Food Cost Metrics</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Labor Metrics</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>


    </tr>
    <tr style="font-size:13px; text-align: center; ">

      <th>Month</th>


      <th>Sales</th>
      <th>Dine-in</th>
      <th>Take-out</th>
      <th>Drive-thru</th>
      <th>Delivery</th>

    </tr>

  </thead>

  <tbody class="current_historical_report">
    <tr style="text-align:center;" class="table_row_append_current">
      <th style="text-align:center; width:7%;" class="sticky-col first-col">Jan-17</th>
      <td style="text-align:center; width:7%;">4</td>
      <td style="text-align:center; width:7%;">5</td>
      <td style="text-align:center; width:7%;">6</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: sorry for that.

Comment: @mplungjan please see the new update. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same method you used for the first cell. Keep in mind that your HTML is invalid, if this isn't some copy-paste error you should really fix it. Like: Having the same amount of columns in header and body of the table. Open and close tbody and thead correctly. I set the left to 7% for your second column, you can adjust this value to have a better result, I think it doesn't fit 100%. But I'm confident you can do this on your own.

```css
table.agent_commission_model_historical thead th {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-size: 11.5px;
  height: 5%;
  padding: 9px !important;
  border-spacing: 40px;
}

table.agent_commission_model_historical thead th:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

table.agent_commission_model_historical thead th:nth-child(2) {
  
  left: 60px;
  z-index: 1;
}

table.agent_commission_model_historical .sticky-col.second-col  {
  position: sticky;
  left: 7%;
  z-index: 1;
}

table.agent_commission_model_historical tbody th {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background: #FFF;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped agent_commission_model_historical" id="tblcurrent_historical">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th colspan="2">Financial Metrics</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>

      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th colspan="2">OPS KPIs</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Food Cost Metrics</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Labor Metrics</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>


    </tr>
    <tr style="font-size:13px; text-align: center; ">

      <th>Month</th>


      <th>Sales</th>
      <th>Dine-in</th>
      <th>Take-out</th>
      <th>Drive-thru</th>
      <th>Delivery</th>

    </tr>

  </thead>

  <tbody class="current_historical_report">
    <tr style="text-align:center;" class="table_row_append_current">
      <th style="text-align:center; width:7%;" class="sticky-col first-col">Jan-17</th>
      <td style="text-align:center; width:7%;" class="sticky-col second-col">4</td>
      <td style="text-align:center; width:7%;">5</td>
      <td style="text-align:center; width:7%;">6</td>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
table.agent_commission_model_historical thead th {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-size: 11.5px;
  height: 5%;
  padding: 9px !important;
  border-spacing: 40px;
}

table.agent_commission_model_historical thead th:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

table.agent_commission_model_historical thead th:nth-child(2) {
  
  left: 60px;
  z-index: 1;
}

table.agent_commission_model_historical .sticky-col.second-col  {
  position: sticky;
  left: 7%;
  z-index: 1;
}

table.agent_commission_model_historical tbody th {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background: #FFF;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped agent_commission_model_historical" id="tblcurrent_historical">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th colspan="2">Financial Metrics</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>

      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th colspan="2">OPS KPIs</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Food Cost Metrics</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Labor Metrics</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>


    </tr>
    <tr style="font-size:13px; text-align: center; ">

      <th>Month</th>


      <th>Sales</th>
      <th>Dine-in</th>
      <th>Take-out</th>
      <th>Drive-thru</th>
      <th>Delivery</th>

    </tr>

  </thead>

  <tbody class="current_historical_report">
    <tr style="text-align:center;" class="table_row_append_current">
      <th style="text-align:center; width:7%;" class="sticky-col first-col">Jan-17</th>
      <td style="text-align:center; width:7%;" class="sticky-col second-col">4</td>
      <td style="text-align:center; width:7%;">5</td>
      <td style="text-align:center; width:7%;">6</td>

</table>
```